# How to make rails stop responding with Cache-Control: no-store

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using Rails 5.1.5.

I have an old/legacy project. Upon request the Rails server always replies with response header

`Cache-Control: no-store, must-revalidate, private, max-age=0`

I googled it and found out that the line `config.action_controller.perform_caching = true` should be true. So I set it so for all my environments. But I'm still getting response with this header that prevents caching on proxies. I suppose it is one of the Rails automagical things that I "love" the most.

How can I disable this?

Comment: Ohh, it was the MiniProfiler Gem.
By default it overrides some cache related headers no matter what you do in controllers
https://github.com/MiniProfiler/rack-mini-profiler#caching-behavior